# calling system commands from rails - general design pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails newbie here, building a rails api backend application.

Here is the broad application flow

There is a single model `palindrome` which has a field `name` of string kind

In the simplest user interaction user client sends `POST` with string `name` to PalindromeController.

This string need to be passed to a system application `systemapp` and the app would return another string. This would need to be parsed as a JSON string and returned to the client.

Questions on how to go about the following.

1. where should I call the `systemapp` from - from model or controller ?
2. should the call to `systemapp` be wrapped in a background job ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Call it from the model.

   If it were a more complex case, you could treat the subprogram as a proper interface and write a separate class for it. This one I would probably put into `lib/interfaces` or even I  a separate gem, as it would contain only code specific to the subprogram, not to your application.

   The lackmus test for where it goes is "will or should your model ever be able to do anything at all without that subprogram". If yes, then it is a case of dependency injection and could go into the controller. If "no", then it goes into the model.

   Rule of thumb: fat models, lean controllers.
2. Do it directly if the performance is acceptable, i.e. if there is no risk of normal user activity overwhelming the webserver. Else, you would use deferred execution, i.e. batch processing, which would entail a very much larger end result.